# What are some practical applications of art gallery theorem?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm interested in finding out some real-life applications of the [art gallery theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem):

> $\lfloor n/3\rfloor$ guards are always sufficient and sometimes necessary to guard a simple polygon with n vertices.

Comment: It would help if you were to say exactly what the "art gallery theorem" is!

Comment: Interesting slides at http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Talks/ArtGallery_StJohns.pdf say that no real applications are known.

Comment: Also, define *real life*...

Comment: I recall it being used in the proof of the Fary-Wagner theorem which says that any planar graph can be drawn with straight lines (really it just needs that $5$-sided polygons need only one "guard" in art gallery language).

Comment: @lhf Very interesting slides, thanks for the link.

Comment: The second sentence in that link starts with `It originates from a real-world problem of guarding an art gallery with the minimum number of guards...`, so that'd be one practical application I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From the book: [How to Guard an Art Gallery and Other Discrete Mathematical Adventures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801892996) by T.S. Michael:

> The whimsical names bestowed on art gallery problems
>   do not limit the scope of possible applications. For example,
>   the scientists directing the actions of a rover on Mars confront
>   a type of zookeeper problem. The goal is to maneuver
>   the rover to various locations, gather images and measurements
>   of interesting features in the vicinity of the landing
>   spot, and send the data to Earth. There are constraints on
>   time and energy, and steep terrain must be avoided.

The zookeeper problem is related to the art gallery theorem but is not the same. Here we are seeking a path of minimum length which meets the boundary of each cage without going within any cage. There are several other such problems (fortress problem, prison yard problem). Many of these problems have been solved by using Chvatal's inductive approach of the original art gallery theorem.